# menu disappear when hover the list item

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors, css-position

when i hover over the hamburger icon in 1000px mode the menu appears, but when i hover over menu it disappears. i have tried z-index and tricks related to position but cannot get the solution.
the issue is in 1000px because in full screen mode i can hover over sub-menu, but not on 1000px screen.
please help, thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ESPN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__logo"><span>ESPN</span> / Media Distribution</div>
        <div class="hamburger__icon__section">
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar__items">
                <div class="hamburger__icon"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                <ul class="navbar__lists__items">
                    <li class="navbar__hover__items">
                        <a href="#">Sports Programming</a>
                        <ul class="navbar__lists__items__item">
                            <li><a href="#">Boxing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fina</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">World Athletics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ncaa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pocker</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Special Olympics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">X Games</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar__hover__items"><a href="#">Content Calender</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar__hover__items">
                        <a href="#">Contacts</a>
                        <ul class="navbar__lists__items__item">
                            <li><a href="#">Asia Pacific</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Europe, Middle East and Africa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Latin America</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="video__section">
        <div class="video__header__wrapper">
            <video src="./6. Exercise Higher Order Functions.mp4" loop="true" autoplay="true" muted>

            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="video__section__content">
            <p><span>ESPN /</span> Media Distribution</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image__section">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright__section">
        <div class="copyright__section__content">
            <p>Copyright © 2020 ESPN, Inc. - All Rights Reserved | Terms of Use | Privacy Policy</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@600&display=swap');
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
}
body {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color:rgb(202, 8, 19);
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.header__logo {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    user-select: none;
}
.header__logo span {
    font-style: oblique;
}
.navbar__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.navbar__lists__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar__lists__items > li {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item {
    width: 250px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item li {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item li a:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar__hover__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.navbar__hover__items > a {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.navbar__lists__items .navbar__hover__items:nth-child(odd)::after {
    content: ' \02C5';
}
.navbar__lists__items > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar__hover__items:nth-child(2n+1):hover > a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgb(202, 8, 19);
}
.navbar__hover__items:nth-child(2n+1):hover .navbar__lists__items__item {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.search {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.search input {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.search i {
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 95%;
    transform: translate(-95%, -50%);
    margin-right: -30px;
}
.video__section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.video__header__wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
.video__header__wrapper video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video__section__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
    user-select: none;
}
.video__section__content span {
    font-style: oblique;
}
.image__section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.image__section .image {
    flex-basis: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
.image__section .image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.image:hover img {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.image:hover > .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
.copyright__section {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(202, 8, 19);
    color: #fff;
}
.copyright__section__content {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .header {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    .navbar__items {
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar__lists__items {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 50px;
        width: 300px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Lato',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
    .navbar__lists__items > li > a {
        color: #000;
    }
    .navbar__lists__items .navbar__hover__items:nth-child(odd)::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar__hover__items {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
    }
    .navbar__lists__items__item {
        display: none;
    }
    .video__section {
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    .search {
        height: 50px;
    }
    .hamburger__icon__section {  
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex: 2;
    }
    .hamburger__icon {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-end;
        margin-right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .hamburger__icon > div {
        width: 25px;
        height: 2px;
        margin: 3px 0;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .hamburger__icon:hover + .navbar__lists__items {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the show/hide using javascript instead of css because the way you do it right now whenever the browser detects your cursor is no longer on top of the `hamburger_buttton` it will hide your menu so it would be better to handle the event with a click instead. Or you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49191392/7864080). Hope it helps.

```js
let navbarListItems = document.querySelector('.navbar__lists__items');
let hamburgetButton = document.querySelector('.hamburger__icon');

hamburgetButton.onclick = function () {
  navbarListItems.style.display = navbarListItems.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: rgb(202, 8, 19);
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.header__logo {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}

.header__logo span {
  font-style: oblique;
}

.navbar__items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.navbar__lists__items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar__lists__items>li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.navbar__lists__items__item {
  width: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 59px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar__lists__items__item li {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
}

.navbar__lists__items__item li a:hover {
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar__lists__items__item li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar__hover__items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navbar__hover__items>a {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.navbar__lists__items .navbar__hover__items:nth-child(odd)::after {
  content: ' \02C5';
}

.navbar__lists__items>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar__hover__items:nth-child(2n+1):hover>a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: rgb(202, 8, 19);
}

.navbar__hover__items:nth-child(2n+1):hover .navbar__lists__items__item {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.search input {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.search i {
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 95%;
  transform: translate(-95%, -50%);
  margin-right: -30px;
}

.video__section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.video__header__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video__header__wrapper video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video__section__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  user-select: none;
}

.video__section__content span {
  font-style: oblique;
}

.image__section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.image__section .image {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}

.image__section .image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.image:hover img {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.image:hover>.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.copyright__section {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(202, 8, 19);
  color: #fff;
}

.copyright__section__content {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .header {
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .navbar__items {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar__lists__items {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  }
  .navbar__lists__items>li>a {
    color: #000;
  }
  .navbar__lists__items .navbar__hover__items:nth-child(odd)::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar__hover__items {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
  }
  .navbar__lists__items__item {
    display: none;
  }
  .video__section {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  .search {
    height: 50px;
  }
  .hamburger__icon__section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 2;
  }
  .hamburger__icon {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .hamburger__icon>div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ESPN</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="header__logo"><span>ESPN</span> / Media Distribution</div>
    <div class="hamburger__icon__section">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__items">
        <div class="hamburger__icon">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar__lists__items">
          <li class="navbar__hover__items">
            <a href="#">Sports Programming</a>
            <ul class="navbar__lists__items__item">
              <li><a href="#">Boxing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fina</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">World Athletics</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ncaa</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Pocker</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Special Olympics</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">X Games</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__hover__items"><a href="#">Content Calender</a></li>
          <li class="navbar__hover__items">
            <a href="#">Contacts</a>
            <ul class="navbar__lists__items__item">
              <li><a href="#">Asia Pacific</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Europe, Middle East and Africa</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Latin America</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="search">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
          </input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="video__section">
    <div class="video__header__wrapper">
      <video src="./6. Exercise Higher Order Functions.mp4" loop="true" autoplay="true" muted>

            </video>
    </div>
    <div class="video__section__content">
      <p><span>ESPN /</span> Media Distribution</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="image__section">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="./food.png" alt="">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright__section">
    <div class="copyright__section__content">
      <p>Copyright © 2020 ESPN, Inc. - All Rights Reserved | Terms of Use | Privacy Policy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i want to do this css way, thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your selector :

```
, .navbar__lists__items:hover
```

The full rule should look like this :

```
.hamburger__icon:hover + .navbar__lists__items, .navbar__lists__items:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since the scope of hover effect is only limited to the hamburger icon and as soon as the hover scope is left, the css does not execute for it so in order to stabilize the menu items I have added hover scope to that `<ul>` too.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
}
body {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color:rgb(202, 8, 19);
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.header__logo {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    user-select: none;
}
.header__logo span {
    font-style: oblique;
}
.navbar__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.navbar__lists__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar__lists__items > li {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item {
    width: 250px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    list-style: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item li {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item li a:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar__lists__items__item li a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar__hover__items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.navbar__hover__items > a {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.navbar__lists__items .navbar__hover__items:nth-child(odd)::after {
    content: ' \02C5';
}
.navbar__lists__items > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar__hover__items:nth-child(2n+1):hover > a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgb(202, 8, 19);
}
.navbar__hover__items:nth-child(2n+1):hover .navbar__lists__items__item {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
.search {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.search input {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.search i {
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 95%;
    transform: translate(-95%, -50%);
    margin-right: -30px;
}
.video__section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.video__header__wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
.video__header__wrapper video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video__section__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
    user-select: none;
}
.video__section__content span {
    font-style: oblique;
}
.image__section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.image__section .image {
    flex-basis: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
}
.image__section .image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.image:hover img {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.image:hover > .overlay {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
.copyright__section {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(202, 8, 19);
    color: #fff;
}
.copyright__section__content {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .header {
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
    .navbar__items {
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar__lists__items {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: 50px;
        width: 300px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Lato',Helvetica,Arial,Lucida,sans-serif;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0.5px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
    .navbar__lists__items > li > a {
        color: #000;
    }
    .navbar__lists__items .navbar__hover__items:nth-child(odd)::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar__hover__items {
        display: block;
        color: #000;
    }
    .navbar__lists__items__item {
        display: none;
    }
    .video__section {
        font-size: 35px;
    }
    .search {
        height: 50px;
    }
    .hamburger__icon__section {  
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex: 2;
    }
    .hamburger__icon {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: flex-end;
        margin-right: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .hamburger__icon > div {
        width: 25px;
        height: 2px;
        margin: 3px 0;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
/* added another line here */
    .hamburger__icon:hover + .navbar__lists__items,
    .hamburger__icon + .navbar__lists__items:hover{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ESPN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__logo"><span>ESPN</span> / Media Distribution</div>
        <div class="hamburger__icon__section">
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar__items">
                <div class="hamburger__icon"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
                <ul class="navbar__lists__items">
                    <li class="navbar__hover__items">
                        <a href="#">Sports Programming</a>
                        <ul class="navbar__lists__items__item">
                            <li><a href="#">Boxing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Fina</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">World Athletics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Ncaa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Pocker</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Special Olympics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">X Games</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="navbar__hover__items"><a href="#">Content Calender</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar__hover__items">
                        <a href="#">Contacts</a>
                        <ul class="navbar__lists__items__item">
                            <li><a href="#">Asia Pacific</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Europe, Middle East and Africa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Latin America</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="search">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </input>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="video__section">
        <div class="video__header__wrapper">
            <video src="./6. Exercise Higher Order Functions.mp4" loop="true" autoplay="true" muted>

            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="video__section__content">
            <p><span>ESPN /</span> Media Distribution</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="image__section">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="./food.png" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="copyright__section">
        <div class="copyright__section__content">
            <p>Copyright © 2020 ESPN, Inc. - All Rights Reserved | Terms of Use | Privacy Policy</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```